# How the Google Chrome new treatment of '#' in URL will influence my OpenUI5 app?

Tags: google-chrome, sapui5

Google show me a new message from end of april 2018 about new feature in Google Chrome:

*Using unescaped '#' characters in a data URI body is deprecated and will be removed in M67, around May 2018. Please use '%23' instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5656049583390720 for more details.*

I use the '#' char in my app only usig the openui5 routing system, for example:

```
http://pathOfMyApp/index.html#/line/14/product/A1B2C3
```

How the new treatment of '#' in URL will influence my OpenUI5 app?
I use 1.42.7 lib version in my app
[image]

Se the new feature here https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5656049583390720

Comment: The change if for data URIs only so it should not have any impact on your app.

Comment: I remember having this issue as well but I can't reproduce it anymore. I believe this is fixed by the framework already. Could you try to reproduce the warning message?